# Does Camera App in HTML5/Javascript work with Android

Tags: android, cordova

Using Phonegap1.9.0 Camera app for android. Followed the steps as per the phonegap documentation. But when I launch the app and click on Capture phone nothing happens.

When I look into the logcat `navigator.camera.getPicture is undefined`

Development version specified below.

- Phonegap version:1.9.0
- Eclipse: 3.7.2
- Android: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- AVD: 4.1
- Device: Samsung GT-S5830, OS- Android 2.3.6

Can someone suggest me the steps to follow and the specific version that should be used to support the Camera.

HTML Code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, 
    initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PhoneGap WP7</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" 
    title="no title" charset="utf-8" />

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">
  <h1>
    VS Mag PhoneGap Photo Demo</h1>
  <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture a Photo</button>
  <br>


  <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Display from Library</button><br>
  <img style="display: none; width: 200px; height: 200px;" alt="" id="capturedPhoto" src="" />
  <img style="display: none; width: 200px; height: 200px;" alt="" id="selectedFromPhotoLibrary"
    src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my JAVA SCRIPT code:

```js
var pictureSource;   // Picture source
var destinationType; // Sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function selectPhoto(useCamera) 
{

  pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
  destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

 if (useCamera) 
 { // take picture
  navigator.camera.getPicture(photoLoaded, onError, { allowEdit: true, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
 }
else 
{
// select from library
navigator.camera.getPicture(photoLoaded, onError, { allowEdit: true, sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY, destinationType:
destinationType.FILE_URI });
}
}

//display image on the screen
function photoLoaded(imageData) 
    {
    var temp_image=imageData;
    document.getElementById("imageControl").src=temp_image;

    }

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var capturedPhoto = document.getElementById('capturedPhoto');
    capturedPhoto.style.display = 'block';
    capturedPhoto.src = imageData;
    navigator.notification.alert("Picture Successfully Captured!");
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var selectedFromPhotoLibrary = document.getElementById('selectedFromPhotoLibrary');
    selectedFromPhotoLibrary.style.display = 'block';
    selectedFromPhotoLibrary.src = imageURI;
    navigator.notification.alert("Picture Imported Captured!");
}

function capturePhoto() {

    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}
// Error Handling
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: check whether your cordova js file is included correctly in the html page.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>

Comment: If you feel like sharing,send me your code, so that I can figure out the problem

Comment: Please find the code used in my APP. This works fine in WindowsPhone. After building the app using Phonegap build, downloaded the .apk file, installed in Android. It doesnt work.

Comment: check whether you have provided needed permissions for accessing camera